# Access volatile field from thread fails

Tags: java, multithreading, field, volatile

I have a nested Thread running in a loop. It regularly accesses a field of the base class (listener). This field may be changed from from time to time with a setter. However, the Thread only reads the first assignment. If I declare the field volatile it does not change anything.

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong here?

Here's an excerpt of the code with the important parts:

```
public class GameClient implements Parcelable {

    private SocketWrapper socket;
    private String nickname;
    private String roomName;
    private boolean isConnected;

    **private volatile GeneralGameListener listener;**

    [...]

    /**
     * Starts the thread to receive messages from the server.
     * Needs a Listener to be set via registerListener() first.
     */
    public void startReceiveLoop() {
        if(!isConnected) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The client is not connected to any room");
        }

        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String fromServer = socket.readString();
                    String[] params = fromServer.split("\\s");
                    switch (params[0]) {
                        [...]
                        case "begin_puzzle":
                            long finishUntil = Long.parseLong(params[1]);

                            if(getListener() instanceof InRoundListener)
                                **((InRoundListener) listener.beginPuzzle(finishUntil);**
                            break;
                        [...]
                        default:
                            listener.unknownMessage(fromServer);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * Sets a Listener to listen for messages from the server.
     * Only one listener can be registered at a time so this overwrites any previously registered Listener.
     * @param listener the Listener to be registered
     */
    public void registerListener(GeneralGameListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried an `AtomicReference` instead of just a volatile field?

Comment: You can start debugging by printing the identity of the listener (e.g. System.identityHashCode or something more specific if you got that) whenever you call  registerListener and also from within the Thread (getListener() ?)

Comment: Note that you should get your listener only once. In the code above, you get it three times, and each time can return a different result in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Yes, provide more detail, when are you changing the listener. You might want to redesign the class and have all the listeners in a map, replace the switch, get the required listener from map.

Comment: Also note: The field is not the Listener. Your `GameClient` `listener` field is `volatile`, but that does not mean that the fields of the Listener object are `volatile`.